# How to split a list of strings into odd and even elements in R

Tags: string, r, list, vector, initialization

Sorry, I'm failing at even the most elementary part of this task.  I have a 50-long list of strings, and I initialize an empty vector 25 long, but even manually assigning the 1st element of the one to the 1st element of the other fails miserably:

```
> p$key
 [1] CA TX NY FL IL PA OH MI GA NC NJ VA MA WA IN AZ TN MO MD WI MN CO AL SC LA KY OR
[28] OK CT IA MS AR KS UT NV NM WV NE ID ME NH HI RI MT DE SD AK ND VT WY
50 Levels: AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME MI ... WY
> st <- character(25)
> st[1] <- p$key[1]
> st[1]
[1] "5"
> p$key[1]
[1] CA
50 Levels: AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME MI ... WY
>
```

Sorry I'm so dense, can you please point out what I'm ignorant of here?  Thanks - EdB

Comment: You're dealing with factors, not characters. Convert `p$key` to `as.character` first. I'm still not clear: What is your end goal?

Answer (score 6):

Your `p$key` is a `factor`, so do `st[1] = as.character(p$key[1])` instead.

Assuming you want character lists, this will give you your splits:

```
odds = as.character(p$key[seq(1,50,2)])
evens = as.character(p$key[seq(2,50,2)])
```

Comment: Folks - thanks so much for that.  Gosh, I'm a real slow learner at R, I hadn't even grasped the implications of factors.  I'm studying it as hard as I can, but it's quite the paradigm shift for me - perl it isn't!  Thanks for teaching me several new and powerful things.  Two R books and a hundred websites didn't reveal the answers you have.  Thanks again -  EdB

Comment: @EdB, do consider up-voting the answers that you found helpful and accepting the answer that you feel best answers your question if it has been solved. This helps keep the "unanswered" question queue more manageable for those who are working on answering old questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
> key <- factor(state.abb)
> key
 [1] AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT
[27] NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY
50 Levels: AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME ... WY
```

If you want every alternate value and want to retain all the factor levels, use:

```
> split(key, 1:length(key) %% 2 == 0)
$`FALSE`
 [1] AL AZ CA CT FL HI IL IA KY ME MA MN MO NE NH NM NC OH OR RI SD TX VT WA WI
50 Levels: AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME ... WY

$`TRUE`
 [1] AK AR CO DE GA ID IN KS LA MD MI MS MT NV NJ NY ND OK PA SC TN UT VA WV WY
50 Levels: AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME ... WY
```

If you prefer your output as character values, use:

```
> split(as.character(key), 1:length(key) %% 2 == 0)
$`FALSE`
 [1] "AL" "AZ" "CA" "CT" "FL" "HI" "IL" "IA" "KY" "ME" "MA" "MN" "MO" "NE" "NH"
[16] "NM" "NC" "OH" "OR" "RI" "SD" "TX" "VT" "WA" "WI"

$`TRUE`
 [1] "AK" "AR" "CO" "DE" "GA" "ID" "IN" "KS" "LA" "MD" "MI" "MS" "MT" "NV" "NJ"
[16] "NY" "ND" "OK" "PA" "SC" "TN" "UT" "VA" "WV" "WY"
```

---

#### Update

If you prefer separate vectors instead of a list, try:

```
stOdds <- key[1:length(key) %% 2 == 1]
stEvens <- key[1:length(key) %% 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return every other element. The first returns every other element staring with the first and the second returns a vector starting with the second.

```
>  key <- factor(state.abb)
> key[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
 [1] AL AZ CA CT FL HI IL IA KY ME MA MN MO NE NH NM NC OH OR RI SD TX VT WA WI
50 Levels: AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME MI MN MO MS MT NC ND NE NH NJ NM NV ... WY
> key[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
 [1] AK AR CO DE GA ID IN KS LA MD MI MS MT NV NJ NY ND OK PA SC TN UT VA WV WY
50 Levels: AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME MI MN MO MS MT NC ND NE NH NJ NM NV ... WY
```

As others have already pointed out using as.character() will convert to a non-factor object that doesn't have all those distracting levels.